Why do I need two/three Vulkan pipelines for GUI presentation
For any that want to plumb Vulkan's complication I wish you well.
It's a badly documented software SDK and here's a perfect example of why it's never clear through context: I want to run an all-C rendering system because I download headless versions with identical software to microcontrollers on robots as well as control stations running same libraries and messages etc.
I am trying to alter a nuklear-glfw-vulkan Immediate Mode GUI from moppers
Without exposure to the internals it's a little like snipping spaghetti in a collander bowl, and it's never clear with documentation from Khronos, LunarG that reads like "a flux capacitor capacitances flux" you need to make 5 errors to disambiguate.
Inside mopper's nuklear-glfw-vulkan.h header he passes Vulkan device instance configuration data about the logical device etc. but only one pointer to VkImageviews from his demo.cpp Vulkan creation where his nuklear-glfw-vulkan creates image memories and binds to the nuklear-glfw-vulkan pipeline.
Here is the code from overlay.c that passes the Imageview pointer from demo.cpp:
void init_overlay(GLFWwindow *_win, VkDevice logical_device,
                  VkPhysicalDevice physical_device,
                  uint32_t graphics_queue_family_index, VkQueue graphics_queue,
                  VkImageView *image_views, uint32_t image_views_len,
                  uint32_t width, uint32_t height, VkFormat color_format) {
  win = _win;
  ctx = nk_glfw3_init(win, logical_device, physical_device,
                      graphics_queue_family_index, image_views, image_views_len,
                      width, height, color_format, NK_GLFW3_INSTALL_CALLBACKS);

Here's mopper's IM GUI header that implements Vulkan code for nuklear.h
But inside demo.cpp he has two pipelines: the triangle pipeline and the overlay pipeline.
But inside nuklear-glfw-vulkan he makes another pipeline aiming at the overlay pipeline's created vkImageViews that he creates imagememories for inside nuklear-glfw-vulkan.h.
Here's mopper's demo.cpp creating TWO pipelines even after the nuklear-glfw-vulkan pipeline.
Here's his dual pipeline creation:
 void initVulkan() {
    createInstance();
    setupDebugCallback();
    createSurface();
    pickPhysicalDevice();
    createLogicalDevice();
    createSwapChain();
    createSwapChainImageViews();
    createOverlayImages();
    createOverlayImageViews();
    createRenderPass();
    createFramebuffers();
    createDescriptorSetLayout();
    createDescriptorPool();
    createDescriptorSets();
    createTriangleGraphicsPipeline();
    createOverlayGraphicsPipeline();
    createCommandPool();
    createCommandBuffers();
    createSemaphores();

    QueueFamilyIndices queueFamilyIndices = findQueueFamilies(physicalDevice);

    init_overlay(
        window, device, physicalDevice, queueFamilyIndices.graphicsFamily,
        graphicsQueue, overlayImageViews.data(), overlayImageViews.size(),
        swapChainExtent.width, swapChainExtent.height, swapChainImageFormat);
  }

So here is my question:
Why do you need the overlay pipeline with his demoshaders (.vert and .frag) in an overlay pipeline when you also create the nuklear-glfw-vulkan pipeline?
He creates a triangle pipeline that shows an MVP triangle model. He creates an Overlay pipeline with demoshaders. Then he creates a nuklear-glfw-vulkan pipeline with it's own nuklear .vert .frag shaders that allocates memories and binds to image memories for textures of the glyphs and icons drawn in a 2D manner.
Isn't the OverlayPipeline a redundancy?
In jherico's response he points at the binding of the overlay images (that were passed to nuklear-glfw-vulkan for pipeline create) into the createCommandBuffers():
for (size_t i = 0; i < commandBuffers.size(); i++) {
  VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
  beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
  beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT;

  vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &beginInfo);

  VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = {};
  renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
  renderPassInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
  renderPassInfo.framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[i];
  renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = {0, 0};
  renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = swapChainExtent;

  VkClearValue clearColor = {settings.bg_color[0], settings.bg_color[1],
                             settings.bg_color[2], settings.bg_color[3]};
  renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
  renderPassInfo.pClearValues = &clearColor;

  vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassInfo,
                       VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

  vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                    triangleGraphicsPipeline);
  vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], 3, 1, 0, 0);
  vkCmdNextSubpass(commandBuffers[i],
                   VkSubpassContents::VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
  vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                    overlayGraphicsPipeline);
  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(
      commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
      overlayPipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 0, nullptr);
  vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], 3, 1, 0, 0);
  vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);

  if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
  }
} 

He points out at line 974:
  vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                    overlayGraphicsPipeline);

that the command buffers created for the overlayGraphicsPipeline are where the nuklear-glfw-vulkan third pipeline commands must end up.
I think he's at least partially correct because the Vulkan command buffers into the submit queue are:
triangle vertexes hard coded into the trianglepipeline:
vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,                            triangleGraphicsPipeline);
      vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], 3, 1, 0, 0);

Then overlay next subpass submitted:
  vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                    overlayGraphicsPipeline);
  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(
      commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
      overlayPipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 0, nullptr);
  vkCmdDraw(commandBuffers[i], 3, 1, 0, 0);

And then every command buffer ends draws.
And here's the bizarre thing here: Why are we resubmitting a triangle AFTER the overlaygraphics pipeline?
This doesn't make sense because that triangle is after the nuklear drawing command buffers from command pools that are externally created in third pipeline? Is the only reason for the second overlaypipeline that you draw a triangle ON TOP of the nuklear-glfw-vulkan drawing commands.
Is there a way to reduce this duplication and only draw the GUI without the overlaypipeline?

You might get better answers to this, faster, if you trim out the complaints about Vulkan and its documentation. The experts you need help from already know all too well the frustrations of working with graphics APIs, so by cutting out the preamble, you help them get to your core question faster.

I'm a writing writer that writes.

It seems like you're asking why there is both a pipeline create here and here.  If you look at the shaders for those, you'll see they do very different things.  The first one is actually a pipeline for rendering UI by doing a lot of draws of UI primitives.
The second one is used here and does precisely 1 draw.
Notice that because of how the overlay is initialized, it's going to be rendering to the images created in createOverlayImages, not to the swap chain images.  The overlayGraphicsPipeline you're concerned about is a very simple pipeline that copies from the overlay image to the swap chain (while not wiping the image currently on the framebuffer that was already produced from the triangle pipeline).
EDIT:
To answer your question about why there's a rendering UI step AND a copy the UI step, it's because the code that renders the UI clears the rendering target.  If you want to render UI on top of output from some other pipeline, then you have to do it like this.  If you rendered the triangle pipeline, and then rendered the UI directly to the swap chain, the UI pipeline would erase any color output from the triangle pipeline.
Also, I notice the UI pipeline only requires a color attachment, while the other pipelines, which target the swapchain, are using color AND depth attachments.
You're surprisingly demanding for someone who's taking a shit on Vulkan in your question.

Thank you for explaining, but why do you need to essentially have a "copy over" pipeline? That's where my confusion lies.

Actually now that I reviewed your URLs I am essentially asking why there's a GUI pipeline created at 888 AND inside nuklear-glfw-vulkan at https://github.com/m0ppers/nuklear-glfw-vulkan/blob/0ec265b9c8931e2613fedf4642888a605e281ae0/nuklear-glfw-vulkan.h#L502  at line 502?

The line 502 code you've linked to creates a render pass, not a pipeline.  They're two completely different things.
